# Is the XBox 360 wired headset compatible with Rock Band 3?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, rock-band-3

we just got Rock Band 3 for XBox 360 and we're trying to use the wired headset attached to the vocalist (wireless) controller as a mic. This work in Rock Band 1 and 2, but it's not working in 3.

**Is this working as intended, or am I doing something wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for *RockBand 3*, but I know that the manual for *Beatles: Rock Band* specifically states that the xbox 360 headset is incompatible with the game.  Have you tried checking your own game manual?

Comment: I couldn't find it specifically stated, but since both games have harmonies, I would imagine they have the same incompatibility with the headset. Thanks!